# JavaScript autocomplete without using a library

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'd like to know if it's possible to write autocomplete, without using a library like jQuery...

I have a simple form, with one input, where I'd like to have autocomplete from an array.

Here's my code:

```
<form method="get" action="search_result.html">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="autocom"/>
  <button type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>

<script>
  var array = ["dog","cat","mouse"];
  var auto = document.getElementById("autocom").autocomplete({
    source: array
  });;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you need to show your own effort and attempts at researching the problem, and then ask a specific question about a specific issue. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<datalist>` tag and reference it in the `<input>`:

```
<form method="get" action="search_result.html">
<input list="mylist" type="text" name="search" id="autocom"/>
<datalist id="mylist">
   <option value="cat">
   <option value="dog">
   <option value="mouse">
</datalist>
```

:-))

Comment: It needts to be `list=mylist` not `datalist=mylist`.